# Grouping with counts in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have attached an xml document called hamlet.xml found here (http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/hamlet.xml).

I am looking to get the following output using xquery:

```
   <speaker name="BERNARDO" lines="38"/>
    <speaker name="FRANCISCO" lines="10"/>
    <speaker name="HORATIO" lines="291"/>
    ...and so on for all the distinct speakers.
```

I have been able to get the name of the speaker using

========================

```
for $s in distinct-values(doc("hamlet")//SPEAKER
return <speaker name="$s}" />
```

=========================

But I don't know how to pull up the lines.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply enough:

```
for $speaker in
  distinct-values(//SPEAKER/text())
return
  <speaker
     name="{$speaker}"
     count="{count(//LINE[../SPEAKER=$speaker])}"/>
```